# Contador en python no está incrementando

Tags: python, django

Muy buenas, en un proyecto que estoy realizando me vi en la obligación de hacer reportes y los hago por medio de PDF que luego son impresos. El problema que estoy teniendo es que claramente no todos los PDFs tendrán el mismo nombre, entonces se me ocurrió la idea de hacer un contador de prueba para poner algo como "PDF1.pdf" e incrementa, pero eso no es así, el contador que hago, por alguna razón, no pasa de uno:(, aquí mi código.

```
class impnew(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = ImpGuias
    template_name = "impa/imp_new.html"
    context_object_name = "obj"
    form_class = ImpresionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("impa:imp_list")
    login_url = "bases:login"
    contador = 0 #Contador en cero

def form_valid(self, form):
    contador+=1 #El contador incrementa en uno cada que entra en la función
    contadorCon = str(contador) #Aquí lo paso a String para poder concatenarlo más abajo
    form.instance.uc = self.request.user

    print("----------Acá inicia algo----------")
    nombrePDF = "ULTIMO", contador #Concateno el contador

    w, h = A4
    c = canvas.Canvas("/home/linen/Escritorio/Prueba/" + contadorCon + ".pdf", pagesize=A4) #Y Aquí concateno el contador en string
    c.drawString(30, h - 50, "Línea")
    x = 120
    y = h - 45
    c.line(x, y, x + 100, y)
    c.drawString(30, h - 100, "Rectángulo")
    c.rect(x, h - 120, 100, 50)
    c.drawString(30, h - 170, "Círculo")
    c.circle(170, h - 165, 20)
    c.drawString(30, h - 240, "Sée que esto es un eclipse pero estoy probando")
    c.ellipse(x, y - 170, x + 100, y - 220)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    ejemplo_dir = '/home/linen/Escritorio/Prueba/'
    contenido = os.listdir(ejemplo_dir)
    archivos = []
    for fichero in contenido:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(ejemplo_dir, fichero)) and fichero.endswith('.pdf'):
            archivos.append(fichero)
    print(archivos[-1])

    subprocess.run(["lp", "/home/linen/Escritorio/Prueba/" + archivos[-1]]) #Aquí imprimo el último PDF generado.

    #comandoImprimir = "lp Escritorio/Prueba/ULTIMO2.pdf"
    #subprocess.run([comandoImprimir])

    print("----------Acá termina algo----------")

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Está algo desordenado la verdad, pero el punto es que el contador por alguna razón no incrementa nunca:'), trabajo con django y pensé que era por que se recargaba la página que uso al crear el PDF, pero ahora envio los datos por medio de AJAX y no se recarga y aún así el contador no incrementa. Me ha dado problemas como "NameError: name 'contador' is not defined" entonces intenté usar `global` y aún así nada. Aquí los intentos que he hecho para tratar de que el contador incremente:

**Intento número 1**

```
class impnew(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = ImpGuias
    template_name = "impa/imp_new.html"
    context_object_name = "obj"
    form_class = ImpresionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("impa:imp_list")
    login_url = "bases:login"
    contador = 0

def form_valid(self, form):
    global contador
    contador+=1
    print(contador)
    form.instance.uc = self.request.user

    print("----------Acá termina algo----------")

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Intento número 2**

```
class impnew(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = ImpGuias
    template_name = "impa/imp_new.html"
    context_object_name = "obj"
    form_class = ImpresionForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("impa:imp_list")
    login_url = "bases:login"

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.uc = self.request.user
    def contador():
        numero = 0
            while True:
        numero += 1
            yield numero
    cuenta = contador()
    for i in range(5):
        print(next(cuenta))

    print("----------Acá termina algo----------")

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Si alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal, o que debo hacer, o alguna alternativa para los nombres de los PDFs, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: No sería `self.contador += 1`?

Comment: @Fedex7501 Eso no lo intenté lo intentaré luego, de cualquier forma ya obtuve mi solución. Gracias por comentar.

Comment: usar la fecha y hora es mucho mejor de todos modos

Answer (score 1):

Después de días, no logré hacer que el contador incrementara:(, pero, encontré una "Alternativa" por decirlo de alguna manera. Como no era necesario que fuera un número en incremento específicamente, decidí que el PDF llevara el nombre según la fecha y hora en que se crea y así que fuera en incremento como quería, lleva un nombre distinto y logro una manera más sencilla de encontrar el PDF en una carpeta por fecha de creación.

**Código de mi "Solución":**

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import datetime
import os

class impnew(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
model = ImpGuias
template_name = "impa/imp_new.html"
context_object_name = "obj"
form_class = ImpresionForm
success_url = reverse_lazy("impa:imp_list")
login_url = "bases:login"

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.uc = self.request.user

    fechaHora = datetime.datetime.now()
    contador = "%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s" %(fechaHora.year, fechaHora.month, fechaHora.day, fechaHora.hour, fechaHora.minute, fechaHora.second)
    contadorCon = str(contador)

    print("----------Acá inicia algo----------")

    w, h = A4
    c = canvas.Canvas("/home/linen/Escritorio/Prueba/" + contadorCon + ".pdf", pagesize=A4)
    c.drawString(30, h - 50, "PRUEBA PDF")
    x = 120
    y = h - 45
    c.line(x, y, x + 100, y)
    c.drawString(30, h - 100, "Rectángulo")
    c.rect(x, h - 120, 100, 50)
    c.drawString(30, h - 170, "Círculo")
    c.circle(170, h - 165, 20)
    c.drawString(30, h - 240, "Sée que esto es un eclipse pero estoy probando")
    c.ellipse(x, y - 170, x + 100, y - 220)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()

    print("----------Acá termina algo----------")

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

El formato que usé fue el de "Año_Mes_Día_Hora_Minuto_Segundo"

**Captura de los PDFs creados con el script anterior**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]